# Is it possible to make the terminal background live?

Tags: terminal

I have terminal open for a lot things and added pretty gradient backgrounds. I thought it would be really cool to have stars zooming or green text falling or gradually shifting background colors in terminal. Does iterm or something have that? What is the way to get live backgrounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch your favorite browser, download [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and install it. Then download [Hyper for macOS](https://hyper-updates.now.sh/download/mac) (direct download link!) and install it.

Then struggle with configuration and install some "[plug-ins](https://github.com/bnb/awesome-hyper)" like [hyper-cat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hyper-cat):

[image]

[Hyperpower](https://hyper.is/#hyperpower):

[image]

[hyper-command-gifs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hyper-command-gifs) or rediscover your programming skills and create your own themes & animations.

---

To install a plug-in (here hyper-cat) do the following:

```
cd ~/.hyper_plugins
npm install hyper-cat
```

Then in Hyper's menu choose Hyper > Preferences. Depending on your EDITOR variable (here the default nano) scroll down, replace

```
  plugins: [],
```

with

```
  plugins: [

  "hyper-cat"

  ],
```

and hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to save the changes. Then reload with <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>.

---

The plugin update error can be resolved by replacing `shell: '',` with `shell: '/bin/bash',` (or another shell) in ~/.hyper.js.

Comment: OMG! But I'm having a problem installing the plugins. When I follow the instructions I get "error updating plugins" check "~/.hyper_plugins/npm-debug.log" but the file does not exist.

Comment: Oh my gosh I'm an idiot didn't run `npm install hyper-cat`. I almost didn't ask this whole question because I was pretty sure that it was impossible. Just goes to show you how advanced developers are

Comment: @ScriptKitty Updated answer to resolve the update error...